# Encrypting a private key with BouncyCastle

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, rsa, bouncycastle

I'm using the .NET version of BouncyCastle, and I have to save a private RSA key to file, obviously encrypted with a password for security reasons.

What I'm trying right now is this:

```
Dim rand As New SecureRandom
    Dim arr As Byte() = New Byte(7) {}
    rand.NextBytes(arr)

    Dim privateKeyInfo As EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo = EncryptedPrivateKeyInfoFactory.CreateEncryptedPrivateKeyInfo(
"PBEwithHmacSHA-256",
 Repository.Password.ToCharArray,
 arr,
 1,
 data.BouncyCastlePrivateKey
)
```

But BouncyCastle is thwrowing a NullReferenceException on the last instruction. Since the method is totally undocumented >:( I wonder if any of you know how to use it correctly...

(none of my parameters are NULL by the way, already checked that)

Comment: Sadly, there is little documentation. The good news is that the source is very readable in my opinion and I encourage you to read it.  Also, it closely parallels the Java version which has a tiny bit more documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That particular PBE algorithm won't work. Try this instead: `"PBEwithSHA-1and3-keyDESEDE-CBC"`